# How do I assign values to an array depending on condition (MATLAB→Python translation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, function, variable-assignment

Here is a portion of the MATLAB code I was able to run (excluding other non-important variables). For context, the full MATLAB program simulates band excitation response in from an atomic force microscope (not relevant to code error)

```matlab
IO_rate = 4E6; %[samples/sec]
w1 = 200E3; % lower edge of band
w2 = 400E3; % upper edge of band
N_pixels = 128; % number of pixels along a line scan
N_points_per_pixel = 2^13; % number of data points per pixel
w_vec = -IO_rate/2: IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel : IO_rate/2-IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel; %frequency vector over a pixel

% build drive signal, define in the Fourier domain
D_vec = zeros(size(w_vec));
D_vec( ((abs(w_vec)<w2) + (abs(w_vec)>w1)) == 2 ) = 1; % drive bins located within upper and lower band edges
band_ind = find( (((w_vec)<w2) + ((w_vec)>w1)) == 2 );
```

Now I am in the process of converting the code to Python. This is what I have so far

```py
IO_rate = 4E6; #[samples/sec]
w1 = 200E3; # lower edge of band
w2 = 400E3; # upper edge of band
N_pixels = 128; # number of pixels along a line scan
N_points_per_pixel = 2^13; # number of data points per pixel
w_vec = np.arange(-IO_rate/2, IO_rate/2-IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel, IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel)
D_vec = np.zeros(np.size(w_vec))
```

However, now I am completely lost as to how I would convert the line `D_vec( ((abs(w_vec)<w2) + (abs(w_vec)>w1)) == 2 ) = 1;` to Python. It isn't my MATLAB code but it looks like it's attempting to assign a value to a function call, I'm not sure why nor am I sure what the line actually does. Does anyone have an idea of how I would convert this line to Python?

Comment: `D_vec` is a variable name. `D_vec(...)` is an indexing operation into the `D_vec` array.

Comment: Note that in MATLAB, `a:s:b` includes `b`, but in Python, `np.arange(a,b,s)` does not.

Comment: I see, is there any particular way you would recommend to replicate this in python? @crisLuengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `tmp = ((abs(w_vec)<w2) + (abs(w_vec)>w1)) == 2` in MATLAB returns a logical (true/false) array where `tmp[i]` is true if `w_vec[i] < w2` **and** `w_vec[i] > w1`. Matlab implicitly converts true/false values to 0 or 1, so checking if the sum is equal to 2 is equivalent to checking if **both** sub-conditions are satisfied.

Once we have this array, we can use it to set the corresponding entries in `Dvec` to 1.

Note that `^` is the XOR operator in Python, and not the power operator. `a ^ b` in MATLAB is equivalent to `a**b` or `pow(a,b)` in Python.

Here's my conversion:

```
  IO_rate = 4E6; #[samples/sec]
  w1 = 200E3; # lower edge of band
  w2 = 400E3; # upper edge of band
  N_pixels = 128; # number of pixels along a line scan
  N_points_per_pixel = pow(2,13); # number of data points per pixel

  #Note the +1 in the second argument of arange
  w_vec = np.arange(-IO_rate/2, IO_rate/2-IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel + 1, IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel);
  D_vec = np.zeros(np.size(w_vec));

  #Find the indices that satisfy both conditions
  ind = (abs(w_vec)<w2) & (abs(w_vec)>w1);
  D_vec[ind] = 1; #assign those indices to 1.

  band_ind = np.nonzero(((w_vec)<w2) & ((w_vec)>w1));
```

Comment: `tmp = ((abs(w_vec)<w2) + (abs(w_vec)>w1)) == 2` can be better (and more translatably) phrased as `tmp = ((abs(w_vec)<w2) & (abs(w_vec)>w1))`

Answer (score 0):

The Numpy idiom to create a new array, whose shape matches a first array and whose values depend on a logical test on the first array values is [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

As I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207946/2749397) in [another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63201952/2749397),

```
D = np.where(np.logical_and(np.abs(v)>low, np.abs(v)<hi), 1, 0)
```